# How can I use UUID in a Views relationship?

Tags: 7, views, entities

Two content types: subscriptions and sites. Each site belongs to a subscription. I use the UUID module, since subscriptions and sites are synced from websites elsewhere. Each site has a field_subscription_uuid field to identify the subscription it belongs to. There can be multiple sites on each subscription.

I want to make a view that lists sites alongside some of the data from their subscription. I thought I would use the Equi Join module to relate a site's field_subscription_uuid to a subscription's uuid. However, Equi Join only lists custom fields (and body), not UUID.

Although I could create a new custom field for subscriptions and sync its own UUID to that field to make it visible to Equi Join, I would rather not because it would be redundant (since the UUID is already a column in the node table).

So I think I have to write a views relationship handler in order to bring a node's uuid into the scope of Views relationships, but I don't know where to start and the API documentation has only confused me more.

How can use a specific node type's UUID in a views relationship without storing the UUID in a custom field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. It doesn't require a custom relationship handler. In MYMODULE.views.inc:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  // Add a relationship between the field_subscription_uuid field and node UUIDs
  $data['field_data_field_subscription_uuid']['field_subscription_uuid_value']['relationship'] = array(
    'title' => t('UUID'),
    'help' => t('Relationship for field_subscription_uuid to node UUID.'),
    'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
    'base' => 'node',
    'base field' => 'uuid',
    'label' => t('UUID'),
  );
}
```